# Binary array present in response is being converted to string in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

Hi I am using axios to make backend api  calls. My response object which is generated using Java has following structure

```
 {
      workbook: [] //array of binary data of excel file generated using apache poi
      userId:<userId>
      
   }
```

When I receive the response given by axios , 'workbook' property which is supposed to be byte array is coming as string. I am not sure if axios is converting the byte array to string. Can someone tell me What is the correct way of dealing with byte data in axios

Comment: Axios doesn't convert byte arrays to strings. So it sounds like it could just be a missing content type header (e.g. `application/octet-stream` for binary).

Comment: But my overall response is a json object. Inside the object only 'workbook' property is of type byte array. Should I set the content-type to application/json  or "application/octet-stream" in this case

Comment: Json doesn’t support binary data.  It’s likely that workbook has been converted to base64 or similar.  Check the Java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import axios from 'axios';

async function sendRequestAndFetchWorkbook() {
  try {
    const requestData = {};

    const response = await axios.post("your-endpoint-url", requestData);

    // Decode the base64 string back to a byte array
    const workbookBytes = Uint8Array.from(atob(response.data.workbook), c => c.charCodeAt(0));

    // Now you can work with workbookBytes and userId as needed
    const userId = response.data.userId;

  } catch (error) {
    // error
  }
}

sendRequestAndFetchWorkbook();
```

Do you want to try it this way?

Comment: Actually  I am using post resquest. Can you please modify your answer for post request so that I can try it out

Comment: @DattatreyaKugve Check it out